# Dependency management with WAR overlays

Tags: maven, build, overlay, war

I have WAR project which needs to be built with different dependencies for different environments.  I am using WAR overlays to set this up -- I have a "base" WAR with all the code, web.xml, and any other resource files, and then I have the environment specific poms which depend on the base WAR and add their own dependencies.

So the env-specific ones look like so -

```
<project>
    <artifactId>myTomcatWAR</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <!-- etc.. -->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>myBaseWAR</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>

    <!-- other dependencies needed for this environment -->

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The issue I am having is that if I include some dependencies in the base WAR (common dependencies needed for both environments), it seems maven does not perform any dependency resolution when the overlay is being applied.  The result being that I could end up with two versions of the same dependency in the env-specific WAR file.

Is there a way to force dependency resolution for WAR overlays?

Comment: What do you mean by `I have the environment specific poms which depend on the base WAR...`? And what are the differences for the different environments?

Comment: The example pom above is a pom that produces an artifact for a specific environment ie. an environment specific pom.  It calls out the dependencies it needs and then overlays the "base" war which has all other necessary items for the war except for any dependencies.

The artifacts are being deployed to different cloud platforms which have different ways of accessing platform services.  I have a library which will abstract those services, however I need to include a specific implementation of that library corresponding to the platform (this cannot change).